# How to configure mail server settings in JasperReports Server 4.0.0

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm using *JasperReports Server 4.0.0* and I want how to configure mail server settings to mail the reports by report scheduling.

How I can do that? Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yahoo settings are:

```
Yahoo! Mail SMTP server address: smtp.mail.yahoo.com
Yahoo! Mail SMTP user name: full email address (including "@yahoo.com")
Yahoo! Mail SMTP password: Your Yahoo! Mail password
Yahoo! Mail SMTP port: 25
```

So it would be:

```
# This file is now just a pass-through for stuff in the 
# file referenced by the Maven js.quartz.properties file.

quartz.delegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate

quartz.tablePrefix=QRTZ_

quartz.extraSettings=

report.scheduler.mail.sender.host=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.username= Your full Yahoo! Mail email address (including "@yahoo.com")
report.scheduler.mail.sender.password= Your Yahoo! Mail password
report.scheduler.mail.sender.from=Your Full Yahoo Email
report.scheduler.mail.sender.protocol=smtp
report.scheduler.mail.sender.port=25
```

Comment: Hi I wanted to know that how many recipients can be there for any scheduled report via JasperServer, because I could just be able to add 25 people in the recipient.  Could the limit be increased.

Answer (score 7):

You should edit the ***`<app-server>/<deployment>/WEB-INF/js.quartz.properties`*** configuration file.

The quote from the `JasperReports Server Community Project Installation Guide` (*6.4.1 Mail Server Configuration Settings* ).

- ***report.scheduler.mail.sender.host*** - *The name of the computer hosting the mail server*
- ***report.scheduler.mail.sender.username*** - *The name of the user in the mail server that JasperReports Server can use*
- ***report.scheduler.mail.sender.password*** - *The password of the mail server user*
- ***report.scheduler.mail.sender.from*** - *The address that appears in the **From** field on email notifications*
- ***report.scheduler.mail.sender.protocol*** - *The protocol that the mail server uses. JasperReports Server only supports SMTP. Note: Your entry must be lower case. For example: smtp*
- ***report.scheduler.mail.sender.port*** - *The port number that the mail server uses. For SMTP, the default is typically 25 (values other than 25 may not work in
  earlier JasperServer versions)*

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have this Installation guide but i am confused in parameters of js.quartz.properties like Host name and etc.Can u give me a example of these parameters for Yahoo? Assume my id is lucky@ymail.com

Comment: Thanks for pointing-out the name of the file to edit, and not just what the contents should be. It's a shame that you can't edit this stuff from within JasperServer's web interface. :(