# Email not sent in Jasper Report Scheduling

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to schedule my jasper report so that at a particular time, it will send the report to the mentioned id. I'm using Jasper Server 4.5.0 and I have scheduled a sample report to be sent to my gmail id. However, it's not been sent to the mail id and it doesn't show any Last Ran time too.

Comment: Did you set properties in `js.quartz.properties` file? See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630528/how-to-configure-mail-server-settings-in-jasper-server-4-0-0)

Comment: I had set the host as report.scheduler.mail.sender.host=smtp.gmail.com. Is this right for gmail server?

Comment: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Comment: Nothing seems to be working. No email is been generated so far. There is one more parameter in the file which I have like: report.scheduler.web.deployment.uri=http://localhost:8080/jasperserver. I have given uri of the starting page of my local jasper server. Is this right?

Comment: I think this is the right value

Comment: Did you check the log files? Did you check the `<app-server>/<deployment>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml` file?

Comment: I have checked the log. It's only Warnings there. No error messages. And in the xml file u said I have the following entry:

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8849/discussion-between-sahar-hassan-and-alex-k)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found it hard to setup GMail as my email server. So once I got it working I posted the details in [this article](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/emailing-reports-from-jasperreports-server/).

In the spirit of keeping StackOverflow answers self-contained, here are the key settings. js.quartz.properties:

```
report.scheduler.web.deployment.uri=http://localhost/jasperserver
report.scheduler.mail.sender.host=smtp.gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.username=me@gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.password=mypassword
report.scheduler.mail.sender.from=me@gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.protocol=smtp
report.scheduler.mail.sender.port=587
```

applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml:

```
<property name="javaMailProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>  <!--as indicated in JasperReports-Server-Install-Guide.pdf)-->
        <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>  <!--NOT indicated in JasperReports-Server-Install-Guide.pdf-->
    </props>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

One observation,

If you´re going to use an email from Microsoft Exchange, you need on more line in the applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml

> ```
>         <props>
>             <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
>             <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
>             <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.required">true</prop>
>         </props>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

in my case works with this

first edit this arquive

/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.1.0/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/js.quartz.properties

```
report.scheduler.mail.sender.host=smtp.gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.username=username@gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.password=your_password
report.scheduler.mail.sender.from=username@gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.protocol=smtps
report.scheduler.mail.sender.port=465
```

second edit this

opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.1.0/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml

```
<bean id=”reportSchedulerMailSender”>
<property name=”host” value=”${report.scheduler.mail.sender.host}”/>
<property name=”username” value=”${report.scheduler.mail.sender.username}”/>
<property name=”password” value=”${report.scheduler.mail.sender.password}”/>
<property name=”protocol” value=”${report.scheduler.mail.sender.protocol}”/>
<property name=”port” value=”${report.scheduler.mail.sender.port}”/>
<property name=”javaMailProperties”>
<props>
    **<prop key=”mail.smtps.auth”>true</prop>
    <prop key=”mail.smtps.starttls.enable”>true</prop>**
</props>
</property>
</bean>
```